# automount a windows share

Tags: centos6, cifs, automount

I have this line and it works

```
mount -t cifs -o myuser //192.168.0.12/Public/Docs /mnt/cifs_shares/Docs
```

But then I try with autofs and it doesn't

In /etc/auto.master:

```
/mnt/cifs_shares/Docs       /etc/auto.cifs_shares
```

and in /etc/auto.cifs_shares

```
Docs   -fstype=cifs,rw,noperm,credentials=/etc/credentials.txt   ://192.168.0.12/Public/Docs
```

it seems that the thing gets mounted actually, but it turns to be empty.

When mounted with mount it's not empty at all

What am I missing ?

I'm on Centos 6.3 64 bits

Answer (score 4):

I had similar problems with mounting a CIFS share on CentOS 6.3 64-bit - the documentation I found doesn't seem to document two additional arguments that need to be set up in the auto.master file for this to work.

Here's what worked for me and might likely work for you (modified a little to fit your example):

At bottom of /etc/auto.master:

> /mnt/cifs_shares     /etc/auto.cifs_shares     **--timeout=600**     **--ghost**

In /etc/auto.cifs_shares:

> Docs     -fstype=cifs,rw,noperm,credentials=/etc/credentials.txt     ://192.168.0.12/Public/Docs

Then do a:

> service autofs restart

Now, if you do:

> ls /mnt/cifs_shares/Docs

And you have the correct permissions, username/password, etc. you should see your files in the share.  Note that the first item in the auto.cifs_shares file 'Docs' is the name of the share that appears in the /mnt/cifs_shares folder.

Otherwise, look for error messages for further debugging:

> tail -n 50 /var/log/messages

Here's another reference that seems to work:

- See the "Automounting" section of https://web.archive.org/web/20140703174307/http://www.lamolabs.org/blog/6000/one-liner-mounting-a-smbcifs-share-as-an-automount-on-centosfedorarhel/

Comment: sixdim, thank you. Your suggestion worked from a Fedora 17 box but NOT from the Centos 6.3 box. It's a progress anyway